# having problems with .replace()

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I'm having issues replacing a "?" with a zero. What ogtL is just a list of numbers that I've taken from an excel file. From that excel is just more numbers.I'm just having problems as to why its not working and I would also like some help on putting the new string back into ogtL.

```
for eachWord in ogtL: #ogtL is a List
    newString=""
    for eachCharacter in eachWord:
        newString+=eachCharacter
        newString.replace("?","0")
    print(newString)
```

Comment: What is the output you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think the problem is you're not saving the output of your replace to a variable.

```
for eachWord in ogtL: #ogtL is a List
    newString=""
    for eachCharacter in eachWord:
        newString+=eachCharacter
        newString = newString.replace("?","0")
    print(newString)
```

You also don't need to iterate of each character like that, I think you can do this:

```
for eachWord in ogtL: #ogtL is a List
    newString=eachWord.replace("?","0")        
    print(newString)
```